# How to update clock from new time data from backend SignalR in intervals

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angular2-services

Now i have the actual UTC time. From backend in SignalR data come with new time in 30 min interval. I have to update time in frontend from time from backend in every interval. I'm starting with time which is created in front and then I'm waiting for new one from backend.

I'm create new date and send this in 1 secons intervals new one which one i subscribe in view by asyncPipe.

```
private _time$: Observable<Date> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
   map(tick => new Date()),
   shareReplay(1)
          );

get time() : Observable<Date> {
   return this._time$;
}
```

This is hub which provides new time in every 30 minutes from server which returns Observable:

```
constructor(private notificationsHub : NotificationsHub) {
  if(this.notificationsHub.dateTimeUTC != null){
     this._time$ = this.notificationsHub.dateTimeUTC;
  }
```

I want to take Data from Observable from in every 30 min and then make from this new infinite Observable which sends new time in every 1000ms. I want to subscribe to this end Observable in asyncpipe in final view.

Comment: You can create a subject and just next the value in your notification and inside your observable which you want to view you subscribe via a flattening operator (mergeMap/switchMap/concatMap) and create a new observable with whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the server time, store the *difference* between server time and client time, then add that difference on each time tick:

```
private _offset = 0;
private _time$: Observable<Date> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
   map(tick => new Date(Date.now() + this._offset)),
   shareReplay(1)
          );

get time() : Observable<Date> {
   return this._time$;
}

constructor(private notificationsHub : NotificationsHub) {
  if(this.notificationsHub.dateTimeUTC != null){
     this.notificationsHub.dateTimeUTC.subscribe(serverTime => {
       const now = Date.now();
       this._offset = serverTime.getTime() - now;
     });
  }
```